# How can Joey be cast in "Days of our Lives" while living in New York?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In the TV show Friends, which is based around six friends living in Manhattan, New York - Joey (Matt LeBlanc) gets cast in the TV show "Days of our Lives", which is filmed in Los Angeles.

How is Joey still frequently around on the show despite filming DOOL in LA?

Comment: But the real days of our lives is filmed in NYC!

Comment: If you visit [Filming Locations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058796/locations) on imdb.com NYC is NOT listed, not once.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[**IMDb** suggests](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/trivia?tab=gf) this is *incorrectly regarded as a goof* :

> Joey is a regular on "Days of Our Lives" while living in New York. But "Days of Our Lives" is taped in Los Angeles. However, **since most characters featured on the fictitious "DOOL" were not actually on the real show, the fact that it's filmed in New York could just be another characteristic to this fictitious version**.

From [**Friends Wiki**](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/Days_of_our_Lives):

> *Days* was satirized on Friends when Joey Tribbiani got a job as Dr. Drake Ramoray on the show.
>
> **All storylines shown on Friends (with guest shots by actual Days of our Lives stars) were fictional and did not represent what was really going on in the soap opera itself.**

So, since the "DOOL" version seen in FRIENDS did not represent the real version, it might have been possible that in the *FRIENDS-verse* the show was filmed in New York instead of L.A.

Comment: However, Friends was filmed in California so naturally when they needed DOOL characters, they didn't have to travel that far.

Comment: So Matt Leblanc the actor was in California, playing an actor in New York, playing a character in California?

Comment: The other factor could be that Days of Our Lives is owned by NBC, which means they didn't need to obtain or pay for rights to the other major broadcast soaps running at the time, all of which were on either CBS or ABC if I'm not mistaken based on some quick research.